# Doctrine Migrations always add the same queries

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, migration

I've been experiencing an issue with Doctrine Migrations for a while. A few weeks ago, i thought i fixed the issue by deleting all migrations files, and make one big clean diff instead. But it seems the issue is back.

NB : i've check the server version already

So, i have this table, created in my big migration file

```sql
    CREATE TABLE hour_synthesis
    (
      id             INT          NOT NULL,
      fiscal_year_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
      month          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      year           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      worked_days    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      hours_to_sell  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      adapted_hours  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      percentage     NUMERIC(5, 2) DEFAULT '100' NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
```

As you can see here the `percentage` field has everything needed, but if i ever start a diff...

```php
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'postgresql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'postgresql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage TYPE NUMERIC(5, 2)');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage SET DEFAULT \'100\'');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage SET NOT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage DROP DEFAULT');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage TYPE NUMERIC(5, 2)');
        $this->addSql('COMMENT ON COLUMN hour_synthesis.percentage IS NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE product ALTER stock_management SET DEFAULT \'false\'');
    }
```

Note that the migration sets a type, sets a default, sets not null, drops the default it just set, sets the type again, and comments with `IS NULL`.
(Last line is unrelated, but it's another one of these migrations artifacts)

Of course, if i make that migration, it works, but next diff brings the exact same code. I tried removing some lines, like `DROP DEFAULT` so that default would actually be set. But then again, next diff is exactly the same.

I tried updating my schema to see what i could see... Guess what?

```sql
$ db d:s:u --dump-sql

 The following SQL statements will be executed:

     ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage TYPE NUMERIC(5, 2);
     ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage SET DEFAULT '100';
     ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage SET NOT NULL;
     ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage DROP DEFAULT;
     ALTER TABLE hour_synthesis ALTER percentage TYPE NUMERIC(5, 2);
     COMMENT ON COLUMN hour_synthesis.percentage IS NULL;
     ALTER TABLE product ALTER stock_management SET DEFAULT 'false';
```

(`db` being a docker alias of mine)

I feel like i'm stuck in that neverending loop of botched migrations, any advice is more than welcome because i *really* don't feel like deleting my migrations files every time i run in this issue.

Comment: Do you do the doctrine:migrations:migrate after making all those files with migrations?

Comment: Yes, he did, as mentioned here: "Of course, if i make that migration, it works, but next diff brings the exact same code. "

Comment: Exactly, i did. And that's why it is an issue for me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Stumbled over similar issue with Symfony/Doctrine ... stopped caring about some day but started looking for different frameworks. In my case there is an index kept renaming from lowercase to uppercase just to be renamed to lowercase next time. schema-tools considered my schema up-to-date except for this renaming, but migrations always want to run all previous migrations just to fail at the first due to trying to create existing table. Using MySQL which should be a considered common DBMS. So this whole framework looks rather bogus to me.

Comment: From the numerous Q&A and articles I read about that, I gathered that most of these issues are due to version discrepancies, especially with MySQL. Sadly I'm using PostgreSQL and this is not the solution for me :/